# How to make child div with text size of container?

Tags: html, css

I need to make child div with text size of container. I mean to grow text and input field to fill all container. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div class="Container">
  <div class="One">
      <div class="Child">
      <div class="MyText">text <input type="text"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.Container
{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 border: 1px black dashed;
 height: 100vh;
}

.One
{
 display: flex;
 border: 1px red dashed;
 flex-basis: 100px;
}
.Child
{
  heigth:100%;
}
.MyText input {heigth:100%;}

.MyText /* I want to make this content 100% of parents size */
{
  font-size: 1vh;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p6z6huvz/9/

Comment: .MyText doesn't fill all the space cause .One has display:flex. Remove display flex and set .MyText height to 100%. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you try to achieve something like this?

You need to use jQuery for this.

You can adjust the width of the container in CSS and jQuery calculates the `font-size`

```js
var fontwidth = $('.label').width();
var divwidth = $('.container').width();
var size = parseFloat($('.label').css('font-size'));
var fontsize = (divwidth / fontwidth) * size;
        
$('.label').css("font-size", fontsize);
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.label{
float:left;
line-height:.8;
float:left;
}
.container{
width:60%;
display:inline-block;
height:auto;
border:1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="label">Text</div>
</div>
```